# How to represent a Fraction in binary

Tags: c, type-conversion

I am working on a personal project which is to create a program in c that takes a fraction such as "1/4, 3/4, 7,5" and output 11100101 <= which is not right this is just to give the idea. But before I do that I need to know what is the procedure of representing a fraction in binary. Any help I appreciate. Thank you

Comment: "which is not right" -- then please show an example that *is* right. What kind of binary representation of fractions do you propose?

Comment: (in decimal) 3/4 (in binary) 11/100

Comment: "1/4, 3/4, 7,5" is not "a fraction", and it's far from obvious how it translates to "11100101" (or any string of binary digits, for that matter). Reword your question.

Comment: Look up IEEE 754 floating point representation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a custom type for that:

```
typedef struct {
        int numerator;
        unsigned int denominator;
} my_fract;
```

You can have different sizes for numerator and denominator depending on your use case.

With this you can then add constructors that take numerator and denominator, or floats or doubles.  And maybe converters to output floats and doubles again, because there is no ``natural'' arithmetic on this type, and if you wanted one, you'd have to do it yourself.

```
my_fract make_fract(int numerator, unsigned int denominator)
{
        my_fract res;
        res.numerator = numerator;
        res.denominator = denominator;
}

double fract_to_double(my_fract foo)
{
        return (double)foo.numerator / (double)foo.denominator
}
```

and so on.